# "Comments can not contain that content"?

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-completed

I tried to comment on [this answer](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/768/64), but The System told me "Comments cannot contain that content."

[image: Japanese]

Why not!? Can we enable "that content"?

Comment: "that content" means Japanese character?

Comment: @JorgeB. Yes, in this case it means Unicode character U+67FF, but in other cases it might mean a whole range of other Unicode characters. I'm asking if we can allow them in comments, because I don't see any harm in allowing them (and I'm hoping my intended comment shows this).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We've had some persistent Chinese spammers across the network, so we introduced a global block on Chinese characters (on sites where we don't expect such characters to normally appear).

Given that the block was only hit 3 times here since introduction and that Brazil has a large Japanese community, I have lifted the block here.

Comment: the message is absolutely cryptic. But maybe there are strong reasons behind that obscurity, that I don't know about. Do you think it would be a waste of time for me to try to open (yet another) meta.SE discussion on improving it? (The only discussions I found are always either related to links only, or sidetracked about the links.)

Comment: @ANeves - consider that is the message were not cryptic, it would give potential spammers a clue as to how to overcome the block...

Comment: I read that as "pretty much", so I won't bother. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Can it be disabled in SOPT as well? See a [request here](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4216/3117)

Comment: Thank you! (Just curious, 3 times comments by "Chinese spammers" or 3 times me trying to submit my comment? I thought the "Comment Everywhere" privilege was to avoid such spam. I guess your Chinese spammers got past this with the association bonus...?)

Comment: @Earthliŋ - can't really distinguish the two, but on the assumption that one or more were you...

Comment: @Math - removed there as well, same reasoning.